# Should I merge these two answers to a question?

Tags: discussion

After the [discussion here](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2218/one-answer-with-multiple-solutions-or-mutliple-answers-with-one-solution-each) previously I have split my answer to this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140880/salesforce-id-fields-vs-3rd-party-text-field) into 2 answers as they are using different tools and have a slightly different approach.

What is the feeling on whether these should be 1 answer with 2 sections or 2 answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the 2 answers are great: more focussed, thereby easier readable and separately voteable.

I would event suggest adding a 3th which is the pure API answer, and explaining how the api messages support external IDs.